# Why do I get gray screen after building APK of my Flutter App?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Some days ago I started learning Flutter with the [Flutter for Beginners Tutorial by TheNetNinja](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ) and today I've finished the course.
So, I wanted to build the app we made and install it on my phone and, after I did it from Android Studio Toolbar's *Build>Flutter>Build APK* and installed the given APK on my phone, it shows only a gray screen.

I've looked for the solution to this on the internet and somewhere I read that it's because the APK wasn't signed.
So I tried opening the *android* folder in a separate window (using *Tools>Flutter>Open Android Module in Android Studio*) and build a signed APK from there, but it still didn't work.

After that, I've read somewhere else that the gray screen I get is probably the equivalent of the Red error screen that appears when there are some errors in the code (testing the app using Android Studio's Play button and emulator), but the problem is that I don't get any red screen and with the "debug version" my app works fine.

So now I'm here, asking for help and hoping to solve this thing quickly.

PS: if you need, here's my code: https://github.com/LeonardoMantovani/flutter-tutorial

EDIT: This is the output of *flutter doctor -v*:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.19041.508], locale it-IT)
• Flutter version 1.20.3 at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision 216dee60c0 (11 days ago), 2020-09-01 12:24:47 -0700
• Engine revision d1bc06f032
• Dart version 2.9.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\leona\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\leona\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\193.6626763\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\193.6626763
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    X Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: can you include output of `flutter doctor -v` and also the error if there is which you get when you run the app in debug mode

Comment: I edited the post with the output of `flutter doctor -v`.
About the error, the wired thing is that when i run the app in debug mode I don't get any error (even though I've read that the gray screen is the equivalent of the debug-mode error screen)

Comment: that grey screen is the loading Screen in your code is  the loading screen , if it is along with the hour glass

Comment: no, there is no hour glass and even if I change the color of the loading screen and set it to blue the app keeps showing that grey screen

Comment: okay i think i get it now ... App is working fine in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, everything works, no problems in debug mode

Comment: can you include the app/build.gradle file? and also are you including internet permission in  your android manifest file in src/main as you also need internet as you are using api calls

Comment: Ok I didn't know that I had to explicit internet permissions, I added that and it worked!
If you want to "answer the question" I'll mark your answer as accepted so that others can find the solution easily (and you earn reputation), otherwise I'll answer myself.
Thank you so much anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml